# Закрепить позицию в ScrollView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Возможно ли как то чтобы в разметке, содержащую `ScrollView` сделать так чтобы он не пролистывался вниз, дело в том что видимо какой то баг, при переходе во фрагмент в API 25 он сразу пролистывает вниз(сам).

Возможно как то применить currentPosition чтоли, но не лишать пользователя листать список.

Comment: 1. Какой язык? 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @post_zeew ну на самом деле не важно, здесь главное суть уловить, поэтому для двух подойдёт.

Comment: Ну если у Вас так пролистывается лишь в одной из версий API, то вы верно сказали, что это баг. И решение со `ScrollView` это лишь хак ;) Думаю стоит разобраться почему у Вас так происходит.

Comment: @Morozov вы правы, в конечном итоге переделал ListView на RecyclerVIew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, используйте любой из:

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollBy(int x, int y);
```

Или, например, сразу проскролить его вверх:

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() { mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP); }
 });
```

Comment: второй вариант идеально подошёл, но если использовать координаты, то не совсем получается. Ну то есть в качестве параметров я использую 0 0, по идее это и будет верхом?

Comment: @Inkognito по идее так должно тоже сработать, например :  `mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mScrollView.getTop());`

Answer (score 0):

Отключите фокусировку у него:

```
scrollView.setFocusable(false);
```